# Jquery checkbox checked get attr id on button click

Tags: jquery, html

How to get checkbox checked attribute id when button clicked in jQuery.

I have list of check boxes with attribute id and a button when I check on checkbox 2 and click button i should get attribute id 2 and so on.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3u6e7qn7/)**

**html code**

```
<div id="checkboxlist">
    <div><input type="checkbox" id="1" class="chk"> Value 1</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" id="2" class="chk"> Value 2</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" id="3" class="chk"> Value 3</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" id="4" class="chk"> Value 4</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" id="5" class="chk"> Value 5</div>
    <div>
        <input type="button" value="button" id="buttonClass">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3u6e7qn7/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Attach the click handler on your button and then select the checked checkboxes using `:checked` snippet. Then `map` the result returning the id values and finally call the `toArray` method. Here is the working code:

```js
$("#buttonClass").on("click", function() {
  var checkedIds = $(".chk:checked").map(function() {
    return this.id;
  }).toArray();
  alert(checkedIds.join(", "));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="checkboxlist">
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="1" class="chk">Value 1</div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="2" class="chk">Value 2</div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="3" class="chk">Value 3</div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="4" class="chk">Value 4</div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="5" class="chk">Value 5</div>
  <div>
    <input type="button" value="Delete" id="buttonClass">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Sjay You're welcome! Glad to help. Don't forget to mark the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/)** to iterate and get the id, use **[`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/)** for getting it as an array.

```js
$('#buttonClass').click(function() {
  var ids = $(':checkbox:checked').map(function() {
    return this.id;
  }).get();
  $('#res').text(JSON.stringify(ids,null,3));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="checkboxlist">
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="1" class="chk">Value 1</div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="2" class="chk">Value 2</div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="3" class="chk">Value 3</div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="4" class="chk">Value 4</div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="5" class="chk">Value 5</div>
  <div>
    <input type="button" value="button" id="buttonClass">
  </div>
</div>

<pre id="res"></pre>
```